# How does one generate a side pane of contents in pdf using Latex?

Tags: table-of-contents, bookmarks

Like the way it is mentioned here: http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=7400

It says use `hyperref` package but doesn't give a straight example. Can you please help?

Comment: Did you try simply adding `\usepackage{hyperref}` to your preamble (as the _last_ package)?

Comment: can you give us a MWE to play with? the `bookmark` package might also be useful

Comment: @JosephWright Answer it? Or do you have a dupe at hand?

Answer (score 2):

I am pretty sure that the bookmark pane is meant here.

Use the `hyperref` package (or `bookmark`, for more sophisticated setups).

The level of bookmarks can be controlled with the `tocdepth` counter and the specific `\toclevel@chapter` etc. commands.

In order to show the bookmark pane opened when the `.pdf` file is opened, use `bookmarkopened=true` as an option to the `hyperref` package. Bookmarks appear numbered with `bookmarksnumbered=true`.

If more entries to the bookmark shall be done, use `\pdfbookmark`, `\belowpdfbookmark` and `\currentpdfbookmark` from `hyperref` or the more general `\bookmark` command from `bookmark`.

```
\documentclass{book}


\usepackage[bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopenlevel=4]{hyperref}


\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents


\chapter{Introduction}

\section{First section of \chaptername{} \thechapter}

\subsection{First subsection}

\subsubsection{First subsubsection}

\subsubsection{Second subsubsection}


\subsection{Second subsection}

\subsubsection{First subsubsection}

\subsubsection{Second subsubsection}

\chapter{Another chapter}


\section{First section of \chaptername{} \thechapter}

\subsection{First subsection}

\subsubsection{First subsubsection}

\subsubsection{Second subsubsection}


\subsection{Second subsection}

\subsubsection{First subsubsection}

\subsubsection{Second subsubsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]